# Download the part of the web page

Tags: grep, wget, curl, html

I would like to "parse" some list of web pages (html), the "parsing" is only about redirecting what's between `<title> </title>` tags to some specific files.
Firstly I did `for` cycle with `wget`, secondly came to conclusion (with `time` of course) that `curl` is a bit faster in this case.

So it looks like:

```
for page in $(cat source.txt)
do
 echo "$(curl -s https://somewebpage/some_sub_page/$page \
 | grep '<title>' -A2 | sed -n '2p')" > tmp/$page/index
done
```

And all these subpages contain info I'm interested in on the line after `<title>` , 
like here

```
<title>
...
</title>
```

so I'm just applying common shell tools to reach the result. 
What's my question. With ~400 pages it takes extremelly a lot of time to load the whole page, then to `grep` it and so on. Is there some more sofisticated solution to load for e.g. only first 10 lines of html document? I rely on classic bash utilities (curl, wget), but you can recommend what you think fits better in this issue.

UPD: maybe it's not the perfect solution, but adding `head` after `curl` decreased script's `time` in 2 times. (duplicate)

Comment: I know the fastest way ... but show at least a few actual urls (for my real test case)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it's just my faculty's web, where several links refer to the several classes. So I am parsing classes whole names from each page <title>

Comment: @DmytroOsaulenko, *it's just my faculty's web* - that wouldn't help

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest anyway the problem is solved with `curl example.com | head`

Answer (score 1):

Try this using a proper [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

### Command :

```
saxon-lint --html --xpath '//title/text()' http://domain.tld/path
```

Check [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) (own project)

You can test [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) (but you need to hide STDERR most of the time (and no `https` support), because the HTML parser is not *that* good as what I wrote as command before)

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//title/text()' http://domain.tld/path 2>/dev/null
```

### Finally :

```
for page in $(cat source.txt); do
    chosen_command "https://somewebpage/some_sub_page/$page" > "/tmp/$page/index"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, solved with `head` after curl

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe what you are fetching to this:

```
wget -4 -qO- {$query} |\
html2text |\
awk '/<title>/,/<\/title>/{print}'
```

Comment: Sorry, too slow with this solution

Comment: ... but with common tools ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the limiting factor with the performance of HTTP is latency, not bandwidth. So I wouldn't expect only loading part of the page to have a significant performance impact. However HTTP does provide a mechanism for doing just this - range requests. And, of course, [it's supported by cURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

However there is no [hard requirement for the title](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html) to appear near the beginning of the HTML content, only that it appear [in the HEAD](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html).

> With ~400 pages it takes extremelly a lot of time to load the whole page

As per above, I don't think you're going to gain much here (although if I'm wrong, then you should be looking at implementing a stream based processor rather than your datagram model). If you want to get the results faster, shard the workload and run multiple handler in parallel.